# std vector holds pointers and variable addresses. clean up?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Say I have a vector which holds pointers pointing to dynamic memory but also addresses of variables declared on the stack, is there a way to safely loop through and delete only the dynamic memory or am I constrained to just use one or the other? or is doing the following safe? I thought maybe the outcome would be unpredictable depending on the compiler.

```
std::vector<int*> theInts;
int* i = new int;
*i = 1;
theInts.push_back(i);
int j = 2;
theInts.push_back(&j);

std::vector<int*>::iterator iIt=theInts.begin();
for(;iIt<theInts.end();iIt++)
    delete *iIt;
```

edit:
I've temporarily changed things to use raw pointers whilst i look into shared pointers, in the meantime could someone tell me if the following is safe? its a broken down version of what my program is now doing

```
vector<int*>theInts;

int* anInt = new int;

theInts.push_back(anInt);

if(NULL != anInt)
    delete anInt;
anInt = NULL;

vector<int*>::iterator bIt = theInts.begin();
for(;bIt!=theInts.end();bIt++)
{
    int* aInt = *bIt;
    if(NULL!=aInt)
        delete aInt;
    aInt=NULL;
}
theInts.clear();
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to create some form of smart pointer which knows whether the pointed to memory needs deleting or not and store a vector of those.

Comment: Somehow it feels wrong to have a mix of local variables and dynamically allocated objects in a vector. How do you come to this point?

Comment: its difficult to answer but i could put it down to poor planning at the start, im optimising old software to use as a port folio. i was using a single vector to step through buttons in an interface engine, some buttons are created via new in the createButton() , some are made elsewhere in the program. ideally i suppose they should all be made in createButton();

Comment: @westr: now you're deleting each dynamically-allocated object twice -- once immediately after you push it onto the vector, and then again in the loop. That's not valid. Once you delete the pointer, any other pointers with the same value become unusable, because it's the object that they're both pointing to which is actually destroyed and freed. And your `NULL` checks are unnecessary -- `new` never returns a null pointer, and anyway it's fine to delete a null pointer, it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only delete a pointer that's either the result of `new` or a null pointer. `&j` wasn't the result of `new`, and isn't a null pointer.

So your code isn't safe. There's no portable way to find out, just from the pointer, whether it points to an automatic or dynamic object.

You could separately maintain a flag indicating which it is, or you could use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers, and for the stack variables set the deleter to a do-nothing function.

Comment: thats a thought, are you saying i could override the delete operator in the class of the object im holding in the vector?

Comment: *nitpick:* It is perfectly safe to `delete` a null pointer. Check **§3.7.3.2.3**. [Edit:] Reading the answer again, maybe I misinterpreted it, It would be nice if you state it more clearly and explicitly, I was confused by the ordering of the words.

Comment: @westr: overloading the delete operator of the class won't help. The deleter of a `shared_ptr` is a different thing.

Comment: @Als: reworded, I agree that what I wrote in the first place was confusing.

Comment: Ive edited my question to show how im doing it now with no variables on the stack, just pointers to dynamic memory. could someone tell me if thats the safe way to do it whilst i look into shared_ptr?

Answer (score 1):

If you write messy code chances are you'll get messy results. You ~can~ use pointers to locals as you do, but you'll end up with your result as well unless you keep clear check on what you do. Here is an [interesting article on new() & delete()](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/17/the-many-faces-of-operator-new-in-c/) that may be of help.